# Android app to delete group of contacts at once

Tags: android, contact-manager

I accidentally imported many contacts by openning a vcf file. Accidentally, because I didn't know it will be imported automatically.

Now i'm looking for an app which is able to delete them at once.

So far, I've founded "Recent Contacts" on Google Play that is Able to sort contacts by their ID.

This is good but not enough, since it doesn't let me to select a range of contacts to delete them at once.

So, in brief, I'm looking for an app which is able to:

- delete a range of contacts by their ID.

Or

- remove contacts based on a given list, say a vcf file.

I don't use Google contact sync.

Comment: You could check one of the contact remover apps [from my corresponding app list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_dialer#group_78) – or export all your contacts (using the contacts app: menu, export/import, export to SDCard) in VCF format, do the cleanup with some software on your PC, and then import the clean file back the same way (after having emptied the contact storage, of course).

Comment: Thank you for the list. In this special case I couldn't get some benefits from it but I'll remember that bunch of contact manager apps for later. For the problem I put some time and I finally deleted all of them manually, but I'll remember not to open anything unwarily :)